# javascript: how can I know where is the .js self?

Tags: javascript, relative-path

I write a small javascript library, it use a image.
I want to build the directory structure like this:

```
/lib
   /mylib
      main.js
      /img
          main.png
   /other libraries...
index.html
```

But if I hard-code the image path `lib/mylib/img/main.png`, my library can't be used in other directory structure.

What I want is to use "relative path" which relative to the main.js self. So that I can write `path + 'img/main.png'` to access the image.

How can I know where is the main.js?

Comment: so if your JavaScript library is included in some page, will the path to `main.js` be something like `http://example.com/lib/mylib/main.js`?

Comment: Yes. (I need 15 characters...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it from your `<script>` tag:

```
function getScriptPath() {
  var scriptTags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

  return scriptTags[scriptTags.length - 1].src.split('?')[0].split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/') + '/';
}
```

Comment: This is a solution.But with this implement, my lib can't work with some module manager like require.js...

Comment: I usually don't use <script> to import .js(s). Instead, I use RequireJS(http://requirejs.org/) to manage them.

Comment: I think that framework actually dynamically adds `<script>` tags to load your framework.