# why does jquery's .load() ignore <script>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a every common page a.html which looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xyz.js" > </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div> ... </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In b.html, I use jquery's `.load()` function to a `div`.

```
$("#myDiv").load("a.html")
```

It works. The xyz.js's content is loaded along with a.html. But why isn't there a `<script>` tag? I open firebug to see the source. There is a's  but no a's `<script>`.

I want the `<script>` because I need it to find relative path.
([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273654/javascript-how-can-i-know-where-is-the-js-self))

Edit: I tried to use `.get()` and `.html()`. Didn't help.

Edit2: The title is not very appropriate. The xyz.js runs. But no `<script>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() call doesn't execute javascript in loaded html file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889967/jquery-load-call-doesnt-execute-javascript-in-loaded-html-file)

Comment: Not really. I added the edit2. my javascript is executed.

Comment: jQuery's behavior is to strip out `<script>` tags from the loaded document BUT it does download those scripts and eval() them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.load()` function purposefully strips out `<script>` tags from the loaded content. When you give it a plain URL to load, it will execute the scripts after loading the content and adding it to the DOM.  However, if you use the trick of adding a selector *after* the URL in the first argument:

```
$('#foo').load("http://some.domain.com/blah #special-div");
```

then it strips the `<script>` tags but it does **not** execute them.

Why?  I don't know.

Now, please note that loading an entire page from the `<html>` tag on down into an element of another page is going to result in some sort of Frankenstein monster of a DOM, if a browser will do it at all.  Generally, when you use ".load()" to grab fragments of content to update a page, your server should respond with a piece of a page, not the whole thing. The jQuery deal with allowing a selector after the actual URL is intended to let you strip out a chunk of a page, which is really cool, but it has that drawback that the scripts won't be executed in that case.

Comment: Finally I decided to use iframe. Thank your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because, it cannot run the script inside the `<SCRIPT>` tag. jQuery has `.getScript()` to call for scripts only. [Check here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: You are not necesarily running the script; think of cases such as underscore templates that have scripts with a special type to avoid parsing.